# iOS UITableView crashes when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, exc-bad-access

I ran into a bizarre issue here. I'm developping an iOS app (for iPad, specifically), and I'm using an UITableView at some point to display a list of things.

Now, when I scroll inside the bounds of the view (not above first element, and not below the last), it works okay. However, it just crashes violently when I scroll further than that, with no other messages than :

- **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** when I scroll down to the last element
- **SIGABRT** with a backtrace when I scroll upper than the first

I looked on Google, and it seems like I'm releasing some objects too much, but I can't figure out which ones.

I also tried running the app inside the Instruments, but the Instruments window just freezes each time I run the app, forcing me to kill it by hand... And of course I get no results...

Here a bit of the related code :

```
    /*
     Returns the cells of the table view
     */
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Create a new cell view
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text = [newestModules objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Texture-Dark-Small.png"]];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-Maths.png"];

        UIView *v = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame] autorelease];

        // Set view background color
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Texture-Dark-Small.png"]];

        // This view will be activated when the cell is selected
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;

        return cell;
    }
```

EDIT: UITableView Load and Unload methods :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Transparent background
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;

    // Generate list of newest modules. Will later look for them on the internet, but for now we only add some test examples.
    newestModules = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Test 1", @"Test 2", @"Test 3", @"Test 4", @"Test 5", nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [newestModules release];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Comment: Does the crash still appear when you comment out the last 3 relevant lines before the `return cell` (this selectedNackgroundView stuff)?

Comment: It actually happens even if I comment out every line between 'Configure the cell' and 'return cell'... That's why I'm a little lost...

Comment: How is your newestModules defined (incl. property), allocated & filled?

Comment: I edited my post with the viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload methods, since I'm allocating stuff here.

Comment: First thing you should try after getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS is running Product > Analyze (⇧⌘B) and setting NSZombieEnabled. Always do that. Most times it will tell you straight where you went wrong.

Comment: I already enabled the zombies, and I got : 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: message sent to deallocated instance 0x78320a0', which confirmed what I thought. Is there some way to know which object is 0x78320a0?

Comment: Nevermind, found it myself. It seems my initial assumptions were wrong. The cells were all okay, it was the UITableViewController itself which was getting autoreleased. Which is weird, because I'm connecting it inside IB, so there shouldn't be any issues...

So, if I add `[self retain]` inside viewDidLoad, the issue goes away, but that's a bad practice, I don't know where it's getting retained/released...

Comment: What is your property for the tableviewcontroller? It should be `@property (nonatomic, retain) ...` in the include file. newestModules also looks as if it wasn't retained.

Comment: Concerning `newestModules`, I think it is retained (correct me if I'm wrong), since I created it with `alloc`.
And there is no property, I set the class of one UITableViewController to this class, and linked it to the UITableView inside IB. I thought everything would work out of the box...

Comment: Oh... Now I see! I thought that even if the child UITableViewController wasn't linked to at least one object (the File Owner in that case) it would still be retained automagically by IB. I checked for leaks, and there are none, so it's OK now. Thanks a lot for your patience ;) I'm going to add an answer for that, might be handy for newcomers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, when you add an object, like a new controller, inside the Interface Builder, it is *auto-released* by default.

If you don't link it with a *retained* property inside a class, it gets released right after its initialization, causing the dreaded **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, the big difference between the scrolling within bounds and at bounds is that at bounds it goes through all elements of the tables, including header and footer, and most likely recalculating the number of rows. If you have a header and footer try to put breakpoints there.

Regarding the EXC_BAD_ACCESS you could put a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to hoperfully know more of who is not correctly released. This is a symbolic breakpoint to define with the "+" button on the breakpoints window.

Comment: I don't have any header or footer actually (I deleted the numberOfSectionsInTableView method)... I'll try setting the breakpoint and see what happens!

Comment: I just tried setting the breakpoint, but it's not triggered, and the same EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens.