# UITableView with custom cell xib crashes EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift2

I am having a `UITableView` which has custom cell from xib file. First 2 cells appears ok (fits whole `tableview`) but when I scroll and I'm trying to customize it's view, object passed from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` seems to be empty and crashes

**In my main class:**

```
//This is last version of fetchThemes, tried many stuff
        func fetchThemes() {
            let moc = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext
            let personFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Themes")
            personFetch.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
            do {
                let fetchedPerson = try moc.executeFetchRequest(personFetch) as! [Themes]
                self.arr_themes.removeAll()
                for (var i = 0; i < fetchedPerson.count; i++){
                    arr_themes.append(fetchedPerson[i])
                }
                self.mytable.reloadData()

            } catch {
                fatalError("Failed to fetch person: \(error)")
            }
        }
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad();
            self.fetchThemes()
            self.mytable.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ThemeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "section")
        }

            //MARK:- UITableView delegates

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return arr_themes.count;

        }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

            let currentTheme = self.arr_themes[indexPath.row] as Themes
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("section") as! ThemeCell
            cell.initCellUI(currentTheme)


            return cell;

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath
        indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 224;
    }
```

**The crash in custom cell xib:**

[image]

**Before sending to cell:**

Before sending it looks like this, but entity is null for this object

[image]

**theme** object seems empty and I can't figure out why. Any suggestions?

Comment: check currentTheme var before you pass it in initCellUI method, it's empty ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Current theme seems to have <null> at entity, but when entering in view it has entity, so it might be deallocated or what?!

Comment: It is inside **var arr_themes = [Themes]()** shouldn't it keep him from deallocating?

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7664131/3378413

Comment: try to disable faults using [yourFetchrequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

Comment: @MihirOza I am retaining it. After initialisation I call a method  from main class that assigns it to a "Themes" object inside child class

Comment: @hal9000 tried but nothing changes

Comment: show the self.fetchThemes() implementation

Comment: see now in main class code snipet

Comment: executeFetchRequest returns an array of Themes, then why not assigning it's result to arr_themes ? You use a local array, then iterating through it's objects one by one and add to arr_themes. Seems overcomplicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95680/discussion-between-hal9000-and-silviu-st).